# Python 3.7 - Logger not showing any log on GCP LOG Viewer

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-platform

I've made a decorator named "logger" and I'm using it to show log on the console.

In my python 2.7 everything works fine but in my python 3.7 code, it doesn't print any log in **GCP log viewer**. (My code is deployed on GCP standard environment)

I've tried to set this code but it doesn't work.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Here's my simple logger decorator

```
def logger(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    logging.info('INSIDE %s PARAMETERS: %s', func.__name__, args)
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    logging.info('OUTSIDE %s OUTPUT: %s', func.__name__, res)
    return res

  return wrapper
```

Even a simple `logging.info` statement is not working.

**I've tried everything with logging, but nothing gets printed out on GCP Log Viewer.**

```
logging.info("Text info")
logging.debug("Text debug")
logging.warning("Text warning")
logging.error("Text error")
logging.critical("Text critical")
```

Here is the log viewer

[image: Screen shot of log viewer]

Answer (score 2):

I deployed the following app to App Engine:

In `app.yaml`:

runtime: python37

In `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.0.2
```

In `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    logging.info("Text info")
    logging.debug("Text debug")
    logging.warning("Text warning")
    logging.error("Text error")
    logging.critical("Text critical")
    return 'Hello World!'
```

When I look at the Stackdriver logs for the application after a request, I see the `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL` log messages as expected.

Is it possible you're looking somewhere else for the logs? From the App Engine Dashboard, you can go to

**Services** > [your service] > **Diagnose** > **Tools** > **Logs**

to find the logs for your service.

Comment: See I've added screenshot in my question

Comment: Can you add more context for how you're using the decorator?

Comment: I'm using `@logger` decorator before each method. so it logs calling function name, parameters and when it finishes logger logs exiting function name and returned parameters. Whole mechanism working fine and loggin log in 2.7 on GCP. Even 3.7 code also logs in my terminal but now working on GCP log viewer.

Comment: Are you deploying this to App Engine or Cloud Functions?

Comment: No @Dustin, it's not working as expected in py3.7, I've deployed my code to GCP.

Comment: GCP is "Google Cloud Platform" which is a number of products. There are Python 3.7 runtimes for App Engine or Cloud Functions, or you might be using a Flex runtime. Knowing which service you're using will help figure out what's going on here.